# Scrollbar webkit properties with <ul> tag

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

In my code I have unordered list inside the div and same time I have added scrollbar to that . I want to use webkit properties with this ul. 
I tried as below.

```
.list > ul ::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 12px; 
 background-color: #e4e7eb;
 }

.list > ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
  border-radius: 14px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.list > ul ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #e4e7eb;
}
```

"list" is div class name. 
But this not work for me. Am I used correct way or any other way to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below css for scroll bar in List div : -

```
.list ul {
max-height: 100px;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;
}
```

For your convenience see the js fiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/harshsetia/z629uxwf/3/

Comment: I have used above css and I have scroll bar also. I just want to customize my scrollbar. For that reason I have to use webkit properties

Comment: Hey dinu, I updated my css as per your requirement now you can see the custom scrollbar. You can manage the scroll bar with css (color & border).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with below code hope it will work for you, but make sure it will only work for the Chrome & Safari browsers.

```css
.list > ul {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.list > ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
.list > ul::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
.list > ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
.list > ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</div>
```